# Preventing duplicate entries in mySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, duplicates, contact-form

I have a contact form that submits all fields into a mySQL database, everything is working fine with that. I want it to however, throw the sender an error message if the e-mail address field has already been submitted. (And of course not submit the data).

What's the easiest most painless way to do this?

My database's name is wordpress

The table's name is wpcf7dbplugin_submits

Answer (score 2):

Alter the table and add `UNIQUE` constraint on the column. eg,

```
ALTER TABLE wpcf7dbplugin_submits 
ADD CONSTRAINT uq_email UNIQUE (emailAdd)
```

if ever you are inserting an email which already exist on the table, the server will throw an error.

Comment: @collin uhmm depends on how you handle the exception.

Comment: The entire point of this method (the correct method) is to check for this unuqie constraint error and tell the user in a user-friendly way.

Comment: you need to have an error handling code in your PHP code that handles exceptions thrown by the server.

Comment: here's an article but don't use `mysql_query`. see how `DIE` was used in Example #2 Valid Query, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php